# Prove that $f$ is onto

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

> Let $X=\{55n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ and let $f$ be a function $f: X \rightarrow X$ defined as $f(n)=55n$
>
> a) Prove that $f$ is one-to-one
>
> b) Prove that $f$ is onto

a) $55x = 55y$

$$x = y$$. Hence proven it is one-to-one

b) For all $y$, there exist at least an $n\in X$ so that: $f(n)=y$.

**I know what an onto function is but I'm having hard time figuring out how to do it. I maybe overthinking this. If anyone can help me if would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Your definiton of $X$ doesn't make sense. Do you mean $X=\{n\cdot 55\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$?

Comment: it's not clear what $X$ is

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: That's what the teacher gave me

Comment: Yes. Whenever I posed it it took out those curly brackets

Comment: See the MathJax tutorial above, @JohnCasey.

Comment: I updated it!!!

Comment: Your proof of b is flawed as it simply states what needs to be proven.

Comment: Are you sure you mean $f: X\to X$ and not $f:\Bbb N\to X$?

Comment: Yes X→ X. That's what I've given for homework

Comment: Your teacher is wrong about both the definition of $X$ and the definition of $f$.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming $X=\{55\cdot n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, it is true that $f:X\rightarrow X$ is injective, it is however not onto, since there is no $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=55$.

This is because if $x\in X$ then $x=55n$, for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and so we need to solve $$f(x)=55\cdot 55\cdot n=55$$ $$55n=1$$ which has no solutions.

Comment: This would be true if the domain of $f$ were $\mathbb{N}$, but he wrote that $f:X\to X$.

Comment: His "proof" of b simply states what need to be proven.

Comment: @Leo163 Thank you. I have edited my answer.